# Why is the XNU revision different from the `uname -a` output?

Tags: kernel, open-source, xnu

On apple's website, [MacOS 12.5.1 is shipped with XNU kernel 8020.140.41](https://opensource.apple.com/releases/)

[image]

But from `uname -a` I got `root:xnu-8020.240.7~1`

```
Darwin devnull 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: xxxx; root:xnu-8020.240.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 xxx Darwin
```

So the kernel version differs from the website, did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source code release is for macOS 12.5, whereas you're looking at **12.5.1**, which is a revision release with security patches. Apple typically doesn't offer source code for such revisions, unfortunately.